# что за ошибка при установке maatwebsite/excel в laravel

Tags: laravel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

до этого стояла переустановил laravel и уже не ставится

Comment: какой то памяти не хватает не пойму где на сервере или что?

Comment: Где ты пытаешься установить пакет? в локальном проекте? php где выполняется? на хосте? в докере? 
Судя по ошибке надо глянуть тебе `php.ini`. для того, чтобы узнать, введи в этой же консоли `php -i` и посмотри локацию .ini файлов. А там уже проверяй `memory_limit`